# MFC: Is there a way to limit CMFCShellTreeCtrl to a particular root folder?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I decided I wanted to split an existing view to add a tree control that will list the folders of the target directories to act as a category for storing items.   I came across `CMFCShellTreeCtrl` but doesn't seem to have a way to limit the folder tree.

I thought I had done something in the past (don't recall the details), but since I dropped it, not sure if I ever got it to work right or not.

Is there a way to limit the root for that control?  Or is there a better control to use?  I really think I'd be reinventing the wheel if I create something.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073213/Extending-MFC-shell-controls-functionality

Comment: I'll take a look, but sure would have been nice if they had made `GetRootItems()` virtual.